# Complicated python regex

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x

I have multiple lines like this:

```
EWSR1{ENST00000397938}:r.1_1364_FLI1{ENST00000429175}:r.1046_3051
EML4{ENST00000318522}:r.1_929_EML4{ENST00000318522}:r.903+188_903+220_ALK{ENST00000389048}:r.4080_6220
FUS{ENST00000254108}:r.1_(608)_FUS{ENST00000254108}:r.(819)_937_DDIT3{ENST00000547303}:r.76_872
TCF3{ENST00000262965}:r.1_1795_ins27_PBX1{ENST00000420696}:r.454_6636
EML4{ENST00000318522}:r.?_ALK{ENST00000389048}:r.?
```

I need something like this as output:

For the first one:

```
EWSR1 ENST00000397938 1 1364
FLI1 ENST00000429175 1046 3051
```

For second one:

```
EML4 ENST00000318522 1 929
EML4 ENST00000318522 903+188 903+220
ALK ENST00000389048 4080 6220
```

Third one:

```
FUS ENST00000254108 1 (608)
FUS ENST00000254108 (819) 937
DDIT3 ENST00000547303 76 872
```

4th one:

```
TCF3 ENST00000262965 1 1795
ins27
PBX1 ENST00000420696 454 6636
```

5th one:

```
EML4 ENST00000318522 ?
ALK ENST00000389048 ?
```

I have millions of lines, so i wanted to came up with a regex for this, however i was unable. I created a conditioned regex, but i am sure there is a much more elegant and easier way. Can someone show me a simpler way?

My solution now:

```
import re
import sys

string = sys.argv[1]
if '+?' in string or '-?' in string or not "?" in string:
    for i in re.findall('\w*?\{.*?\}:r\.[\(\)\?\+\-\d]*_[\(\)\?\+\-\d]*', string):
        if 'ins' in i:
            print(re.findall('ins[A-Za-z0-9]*', i)[0])
            i = re.sub('ins[A-Za-z0-9]*', "", i)
        print(i.lstrip('_').split('{')[0], re.findall('\{(.*?)\}', i.lstrip('_'))[0], " ".join(i.lstrip('_').split('r.')[-1].split('_')))

else:
    for i in re.findall('\w*?\{.*?\}:r\.\?', string):
        if 'ins' in i:
            print(re.findall('ins[A-Za-z0-9]*', i)[0])
            i = re.sub('ins[A-Za-z0-9]*', "", i)
        print(i.lstrip('_').split('{')[0], re.findall('\{(.*?)\}', i.lstrip('_'))[0], " ".join(i.lstrip('_').split('r.')[-1].split('_')))
```

Comment: Something like split on `(\{|\}:r\.|_)`? [See it here at regex101](https://regex101.com/r/cu1WSu/3).

Comment: I tried that as well, the problem was there that the "numbers" are connected to the wrong identifiers. Like `1_1364_FLI1` but the 1_1364...` should go with `EWSR1`. And in case there are a lot of identifiers in a line i got lost reallocating em

Comment: Try [`([a-zA-Z]\w*)\{([^{}]*)\}:r\.(?:([-()?+\d]+))?(?:_([-()?+\d]+))?`](https://regex101.com/r/21roQD/1)

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Nice one, but fails at the `ins...` type of lines

Comment: And [`((?<![^_])ins\d+)_|([a-zA-Z]+[0-9]*)\{([^{}]*)\}:r\.(?:([-()?+\d]+))?(?:_([-()?+\d]+))?`](https://regex101.com/r/21roQD/3)?

Comment: How did you end up with what are presumably gene/transcript/protein names and IDs in this format? Could they not have been generated in a more parsable format?

Comment: How about a two stage rocket ;) First split on this `(?<=\d|\))_(?=[a-z])` [here at regex101](https://regex101.com/r/cu1WSu/5), then on this `(\{|}:r\.|_)` - [here](https://regex101.com/r/cu1WSu/6).

Comment: @Chris_Rands Sadly this is from an online database. The saddest thing that it is from one of the most used one. COSMIC

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a one regex solution, that might not be so elegant, but working:

```
((?<![^_])ins\d+)_|([a-zA-Z]+[0-9]*)\{([^{}]*)\}:r\.([-()?+\d]+)?(?:_([-()?+\d]+))?
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/21roQD/4)

*Details*:

- `((?<![^_])ins\d+)_` - Group 1 capturing `ins` (not preceded with a char other than `_`) with one or more digits after and then `_`
- `|` - or
- `([a-zA-Z]+[0-9]*)` - 1+ ASCII letters followed with 0+ digits (if they can be intermingled, use `\w*` instead of `[0-9]*`)
- `\{([^{}]*)\}` - a `{...}` substring with the contents (that can have no `{` nor `}`) captured into Group 2
- `:r\.` -  literal char sequence `:r.`
- `([-()?+\d]+)?` - an optional capturing group (ID 3) matching `-`, `(`, `)`, `?`, `+`, or a digit 1 or more times greedily
- `(?:_([-()?+\d]+))?` - an optional non-capturing group matching `_` and capturing into Group 4 the same subpattern as above.

[Python demo](https://ideone.com/GUDur7):

```
import re
regex = r"((?<![^_])ins\d+)_|([a-zA-Z]+[0-9]*)\{([^{}]*)\}:r\.([-()?+\d]+)?(?:_([-()?+\d]+))?"
test = ["EWSR1{ENST00000397938}:r.1_1364_FLI1{ENST00000429175}:r.1046_3051",
    "EML4{ENST00000318522}:r.1_929_EML4{ENST00000318522}:r.903+188_903+220_ALK{ENST00000389048}:r.4080_6220",
    "FUS{ENST00000254108}:r.1_(608)_FUS{ENST00000254108}:r.(819)_937_DDIT3{ENST00000547303}:r.76_872",
    "TCF3{ENST00000262965}:r.1_1795_ins27_PBX1{ENST00000420696}:r.454_6636",
    "EML4{ENST00000318522}:r.?_ALK{ENST00000389048}:r.?"]
res = []
for s in test:
    for match in re.finditer(regex, s):
        tmp = []
        for groupNum in range(0, len(match.groups())):
            if match.group(groupNum+1):
                tmp.append(match.group(groupNum+1))
        res.append(tmp)
print(res)
```

Results:

```
[
 ['EWSR1', 'ENST00000397938', '1', '1364'],
 ['FLI1', 'ENST00000429175', '1046', '3051'],

 ['EML4', 'ENST00000318522', '1', '929'],
 ['EML4', 'ENST00000318522', '903+188', '903+220'],
 ['ALK', 'ENST00000389048', '4080', '6220'],

 ['FUS', 'ENST00000254108', '1', '(608)'],
 ['FUS', 'ENST00000254108', '(819)', '937'],
 ['DDIT3', 'ENST00000547303', '76', '872'],

 ['TCF3', 'ENST00000262965', '1', '1795'],
 ['ins27'],
 ['PBX1', 'ENST00000420696', '454', '6636'],

 ['EML4', 'ENST00000318522', '?'],
 ['ALK', 'ENST00000389048', '?']
]
```

Comment: I hope it works for you. If you need more details or help on this subject, please feel free to drop a comment here.

Answer (score 3):

First split on `(?<=\d|\)|\?)_(?=[a-z])` and you'll end up with the *records* separated, like this:

```
EWSR1{ENST00000397938}:r.1_1364
FLI1{ENST00000429175}:r.1046_3051
EML4{ENST00000318522}:r.1_929
EML4{ENST00000318522}:r.903+188_903+220
ALK{ENST00000389048}:r.4080_6220
FUS{ENST00000254108}:r.1_(608)
FUS{ENST00000254108}:r.(819)_937
DDIT3{ENST00000547303}:r.76_872
TCF3{ENST00000262965}:r.1_1795
ins27
PBX1{ENST00000420696}:r.454_6636
EML4{ENST00000318522}:r.?
ALK{ENST00000389048}:r.?
```

[See it here at regex101](https://regex101.com/r/cu1WSu/7).

Then replace the result again by `(\{|}:r\.|_)`  with , ending up like [here on regex101](https://regex101.com/r/cu1WSu/9).

This will give you

```
EWSR1 ENST00000397938 1 1364
FLI1 ENST00000429175 1046 3051
EML4 ENST00000318522 1 929
EML4 ENST00000318522 903+188 903+220
ALK ENST00000389048 4080 6220
FUS ENST00000254108 1 (608)
FUS ENST00000254108 (819) 937
DDIT3 ENST00000547303 76 872
TCF3 ENST00000262965 1 1795
ins27
PBX1 ENST00000420696 454 6636
EML4 ENST00000318522 ?
ALK ENST00000389048 ?
```

Answer (score 1):

First split with "_(?=[a-zA-Z]".Then split whith "[}{:._r]"

```
import re
with open('file.txt') as f:
    for l in f:
        print "\n".join(map(lambda x:" ".join(re.split(r'[}{:._r]',x)),re.split(r'_(?=[a-zA-Z])',l.strip('\n'))))+'\n'
```